# Switch between two partial views which are in the same position

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have two partial views: Food and Drink.

I have one view with fixed left side. I want the right side to switch between Food and Drinks. Here is the place I want them both (of course not in the same time) to show:

```
<table width="100%">
    .................Food/Drink
</table>
```

I have two buttons on the right side. If button1 is clicked, the Food view should be rendered. button2 => Drink. Drink and Food should appear in the same position. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use jQuery hide / show methods or just toggle.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

If you want to dynamically load the content of those partial views you can use jQuery load

http://api.jquery.com/load/

PS. Instead of tables try using divs for your layout.

Comment: Just render them side to side and when you hide one the other will fall in its place.

Comment: Do you mean like this:

                    <table width="100%">
                        <div id="someId"><%Html.RenderPartial("Food"); %></div>
<div id="someId1"><%Html.RenderPartial("Drink"); %></div>
                    </table>

And then just show and hide to someId and someId1?

Comment: No, just delete <table>. Or use <div> instead.